# Implementing TCP Server with Python-How to?

Tags: python, server, tcp

I have searched a lot on the forums for implementing TCP server using Python. All that I could find is a multi-threaded approach to TCP Server Implementation on a single port for interacting with clients.

I am looking for Server sample code for creating sockets using different ports.I have clients with distinct port numbers.For example, One socket binding IP and portNo-2000 and second one binding IP and another port No. 3000 and so on. Could anybody provide pointers?

Comment: why won't you just use a server that has multipole client's (with 1 socket)?

Comment: Do you know which ports you need in advance? Then you could use http://pymotw.com/2/socket/tcp.html to bind as many ports as you need

Answer (score 0):

```
import socket
from typing import Union


SERVERS_PORT_LIST = []


def start_server(port) -> Union[socket.socket, None]:
    server_socket = socket.socket()
    try:
        server_socket.bind(("0.0.0.0", port))
        server_socket.listen()
        return server_socket
    except (socket.error, OSError):  # in case the port is taken
        return None


def accept_client(server_sock: socket.socket) -> Union[tuple[socket.socket, tuple[str, str]], tuple[None, None]]:
    # wait 5 seconds for a client to connect, if no one
    # tries to connect within 5 seconds it will return None
    server_sock.settimeout(5)
    try:
        client_socket, client_addr = server_sock.accept()
        return client_socket, client_addr
    except (socket.error, ConnectionRefusedError):
        return None, None


def main():
    servers_client_sockets = {}
    # create all the servers
    for port in SERVERS_PORT_LIST:
        server_sock = start_server(port)
        if server_sock is not None:
            servers_client_sockets[(server_sock, port)] = []
        else:
            print(f"Port {port} is taken.")
    # accept 1 client for each server and append the client to the list inside the dict
    # that contains {server_sock: [list of clients], server_sock2: [list of clients], ...}
    for server_sock, port in servers_client_sockets.keys():
        client_socket, client_addr = accept_client(server_sock)
        if client_socket is not None:  # someone connected
            servers_client_sockets[(server_sock, port)] = servers_client_sockets[server_sock].append(client_socket)
        else:
            print(f"No client on port {port}.")
    # handle the client in each server sock


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

---

### answer to your question:

I have made a little change to the code.

to receive a client data you need to go through the dict `servers_client_sockets` keys, and search for the port you want to receive from.

the dict is built like the following: `{(server_sock, port): [clients], (server_2_sock, port): [clients], ..., (server_x_sock, port): [clients]}`

example:

```
for server_sock, port in servers_client_sockets.keys():
    if port == the_port_you_want:
        client_list = servers_client_sockets[(server_sock, port)]
```

now `client_list` should contains all the clients that connected to the port you were looking for.
if there is only one client in each port you can do this:

```
data clients_list[1].recv(a_number_that_says_how_many_bytes_to_recv).decode()
# with out '.decode()' if you want to keep the data as bytes
```

**if there is more than one client you will need to do a loop on the code from above (receive the data for each one of the clients)**

---

NOTE:

if you want to accept more than 1 client you will need to add more code, and insert the client socket to the dict `servers_client_sockets` (I explained above how the dict is built).

use this code to accept 1 more client for each server port

```
# loops on all the server sockets
for server_sock, port in servers_client_sockets.keys():
        # tries to accept a client for each server socket
        client_socket, client_addr = accept_client(server_sock)
        # if there is a new client it adds it to the dict servers_client_sockets
        if client_socket is not None:  # someone connected
            servers_client_sockets[(server_sock, port)] = servers_client_sockets[server_sock].append(client_socket)
        # if there is no new client, it prints no client on port x
        else:
            print(f"No client on port {port}.")
```

Comment: Santiago, my ports are well known. I have a legacy application where server listens from 3 distinct ports. But could not figure out the code from the link provided by you . btw how do I read the data,  from each client. I also need to redirect the processed data to clients

Comment: put all your ports in the list `SERVERS_PORT_LIST` (at the top of the code, for example: `SERVERS_PORT_LIST = [8820, 6789, 498, ...]`)

Comment: look at the answer, I changed the code a bit and explained how to receive data from the clients

Comment: I also need some error handling. If the client disconnects, then server has to retry for some period and then go to listen mode. Any suggestions?

Comment: `try` `except` block for error handling. in the `except` block just call the `accept_client` function (in a while loop) until a client connects.

Answer (score 0):

Using `asyncio` you can write elegant multi-servers and clients without having to use more than one thread or having to invert the control flow for efficient single-threaded non-blocking I/O.

`asyncio` allows one to:

- write I/O code in straight-forward sequential/blocking manner, which in the past required using one thread per connection;
- execute this code using only one thread of execution in non-blocking fashion, which in the past required inverting the control flow of your sequential blocking I/O code into callback-hell based programming model.

You can find example TCP server and client in Python Standard library documentation, [`asyncio` examples](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-protocol.html#asyncio-example-tcp-echo-server-protocol).

Server:

```
import asyncio


class EchoServerProtocol(asyncio.Protocol):
    def connection_made(self, transport):
        peername = transport.get_extra_info('peername')
        print('Connection from {}'.format(peername))
        self.transport = transport

    def data_received(self, data):
        message = data.decode()
        print('Data received: {!r}'.format(message))

        print('Send: {!r}'.format(message))
        self.transport.write(data)

        print('Close the client socket')
        self.transport.close()


async def main():
    # Get a reference to the event loop as we plan to use
    # low-level APIs.
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()

    server = await loop.create_server(
        lambda: EchoServerProtocol(),
        '127.0.0.1', 8888)

    async with server:
        await server.serve_forever()


asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: btw, can I add a different IP other than loopback address on my PC?

Comment: @gari https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost "IPv4 network standards reserve the entire address block 127.0.0.0/8 (more than 16 million addresses) for loopback purposes. That means any packet sent to any of those addresses is looped back. The address 127.0.0.1 is the standard address for IPv4 loopback traffic; the rest are not supported by all operating systems."